# NSJSONSerialization works on iOS6 but not on iOS5.1

Tags: ios, nsjsonserialization, ios5

I'm working on restoring iOS5.1 compatibility to an app I shipped which requires 6.0 currently.

This code works perfectly under 6.0 but when running under 5.1 parsing returns a null object and an error when parsing the exact same JSON result.

I tried weak linking the Foundation framework

The jsonError is -

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Duplicate key for object around character 8.) UserInfo=0x11d58530 {NSDebugDescription=Duplicate key for object around character 8.}`

I have validated my JSON set with and there is only a single instance of the object type at character 8 and character 8 is simply a colon:

```
{"site":{
```

Here's the code...

```
NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
NSError *jsonError;
NSDictionary *responseDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&jsonError];

if ((responseData == nil) || (responseDict == nil)) {
   // I only get here when running on 5.1            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try a different reading option for the JSONSerialization?

```
NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
```

That is what I use for my iOS 6 version of my project

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In this case the top level object is a dictionary so that option won't do me any good. Any the iOS6 version works perfectly it's when running on 5.x that this code does not work.